# Update CanvasContent1 on Modern Pages programmatically

Tags: content, update, modern

I have a client requirement to update the contents of a modern page programmatically. The client has an English version of the page and a Spanish version.  Whenever the English version is updated, I need to grab the content under CanvasContent1, get it translated into Spanish, and then update the Spanish version of that page.  What is the best approach to accomplish this? On classic pages, I am updating the field based on the field GUID.  Does CanvasContent1 have a unique GUID that I can use to update its contents or is there a better approach?